# ExpressJS does not seem to work with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to figure out Node.js to use as an api to do GET, POST, etc. I've been stuck trying to figure out why this post is not working.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
        method: "POST", 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "localhost:8000/login", 
        data: JSON.stringify({user:"john", pass:"123"}),
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

In my express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var user = req.body.user;
  var password = req.body.pass;
  if(user == 'john' && password == '123') {
    res.status(200);
  } else {
    res.status(401);
  }
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm always getting the 'error' alert which means that the ajax call was not successful. which it should be.

Comment: your server is running? and your code front-end is running on same server?

Comment: Your URL needs to be a valid URL such as `http://localhost:8000/login` or a valid relative URL `/login` that will assume the protocol, domain and port of the host web page.  `localhost:8000/login` is neither.  If you looked at the detail of the error you were getting in the Ajax call or you looked at the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see exactly what was happening on the network, you'd probably get some pretty good hints as to what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you should return some response from your express code, also response should be ended especially in case of just sending only the status code like `res.status(401);`

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.user;
    var password = req.body.pass;
    if(user == 'john' && password == '123') {
        res.status(200).json({t:1});
    } else {
        res.status(401);
    }

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that status() does not do so but sendStatus() and other methods do.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just incomplete.  But he does explain what he's suggesting and why.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/login",
        data: JSON.stringify({user:"john", pass:"123"}),
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
    app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = req.body.user;
    var password = req.body.pass;
    if(user == 'john' && password == '123') {
    res.status(200).json({s: 1});
    } else {
    res.status(401).json({e: 2});
    }
   });
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Because you didn't actually answer the question or explain what the OP was doing wrong. You just assert that your Ajax call works. Further, it doesn't address what the other answer does that the server code is also wrong.

Comment: @Paul, I am so sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.stringify({user:"john", pass:"123"});

$.ajax({ 
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/login", 
    data: json
}).done(function(data){
    console.log("works fine");
});
```

Should work for an Ajax post function, sending the data to the node server.
The url needs to match the url of the app.post in the node server file, you don't need localhost in front of it.
ContentType is also not necessary and I made the json object outside of the Ajax call instead of setting it inside the Ajax call.

```
var express = require('express');
var parser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var port = 8000;

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.user;
    var password = req.body.pass;

    if(user == "john" && password == "123") {
        res.status(200);
    } else {
        res.status(401);
    }
});

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

And that should work for the node server itself.
I set the server running, so you can always keep track of what port it's listening on, so you don't need to bother scrolling down to change the port, just change the port at the top of your file.
Further the `/login` was looking fine to me.
Also, I edited the app.use statements and added an extra one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to parse request to JSON.

your code is:-

```
$.ajax({ 
        method: "POST", 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "localhost:8000/login", 

        //here you used JSON.stringify and on server side you have to parse it to use 'user' and 'pass' as a key of json

        data: JSON.stringify({user:"john", pass:"123"}),
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

on the server side

```
<br>
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

//parse data to JSON for further use
  var dataObj = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  if(dataObj.user == 'john' && dataObj.password == '123') {
    res.status(200);
  } else {
    res.status(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your server side logic won't actually finish the response, client will timeout.

Comment: use res.send() function which will return your data to ajax success function